# Populate two different tables

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to populate two different tables on change of two different selectors, each one should point to the corresponding table. I have try different thing but i think I'm looking the wrong way. Any idea? Any hint?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint2"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your question? What is not working?

Comment: You are right, i should be more specific on the question. It will be: How i make my script to point the corresponding table on change of the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a second parameter to your function, as such:

```
function showUser(str, hintId) { /* ... */}
```

Add pass the element id of the current hint div, like so:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value, 'txtHint')">
...
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value, 'txtHint2')">
```

Then, anywhere in your code when you are using `getElementById` use the `hintId` parameter.

```
document.getElementById(hintId).innerHTML="";
```

Comment: Should do the trick. If you come across any trouble ask away, otherwise it'd be nice of you to rank the answer :)

Comment: WOW WOW WOW, work like a charm! :) I'm kind of new so i'm getting to know the dynamic around ranking answers and that stuff. Thanks a lot @iMoses.